Как сделать такую фигуру? На css
Как сделать такой треугольник на css ?



.header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 25px;
    max-width: 156px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 24px 25px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(10, 40, 107, 0.05);
    list-style: none;
}

.header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 9px solid #fcf921;
    border-left: 18px solid transparent;
    border-right: 18px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 25px;
    top: 0;
    right: 19px;
}
                        <ul class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_menu">
                            <div class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper">
                                <li class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_menu-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_menu-link text-gr-16-14">
                                        Предстоящие
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_menu-item">
                                    <a class="header__wrapper-nav_list-inner_menu-link text-gr-16-14" href="#">
                                        Прошедшие
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </div>
                        </ul>




https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkML640BcoA & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zJkV0DIXeY

Вот так это можно реализовать, если я правильно поняла Вашу задачу


.header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20%;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}
a.disabled {
  color: lightgray;
}
<div class="header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Предстоящие</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="disabled">Прошедшие</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>



и вариант с хитринкой (скругленный треугольник)


.header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 20%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: -15px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

a.disabled {
  color: lightgray;
}
<div class="header_wrapper-nav_list-inner_wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Предстоящие</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="disabled">Прошедшие</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>




Возможно ли как то закруглить углы у самой пимпочки?

@Майя, добавила вариант со скруглением

Спасибо, за помощь

@Майя, рада была помочь



body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.popover__title {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.popover__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popover__content {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 320px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  background-color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.popover__content:before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  content: "";
  right: calc(50% - 10px);
  top: -8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #bfbfbf transparent;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-property: transform;
}

.popover__wrapper:hover .popover__content {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.75, -0.02, 0.2, 0.97);
}

.popover__message {
  text-align: center;
}
<div class="popover__wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <h2 class="popover__title">Hover me</h2>
  </a>
  <div class="popover__content">
    <p class="popover__message">Popover</p>
  </div>
</div>




Возможно ли как то закруглить углы у самой пимпочки?
